# How can I include the template_dir in django settings

Tags: python, django

In the django `settings.py` its asking for `TEMPLATE_DIR`.

Rather than hard coding the path there I want to have templates folder inside the each app, e.g.

```
coresite/templates
blog/templates
gallery/templates
```

How can make that generic? Or do I have to add the templates for each app I have in my base site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` to `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` in the `settings.py` file, which will try to load templates from each installed app's `templates` sub directory.

e.g.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

More info: [Template loader types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)

Comment: i tried that , i had the template in basesite/index.html and it could not find it. then i hard coded that path in template_dir and then it found that

Comment: @user32, is _index.html_ your template and _basesite_ is your app? Then you should put _index.html_ in _basesite/templates_ directory and update settings as said in answer.